# iOS: Do blocks retain the stack frame?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

In order for blocks to work can retain the local variables they have to have access to stack frame.

Because the frame has to persist after the function has exited I assume that what the block deals with is a copy of the original stack frame.

Does the stack frame retain a block or does the block retain the stack frame?

Do queues retain the blocks that are in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks do not retain a stack frame. Stack variables referenced by a block are referenced on the stack until the block is moved to the heap. At that time, any automatic variables are copied along with the block, and any `__block` variables are copied to the heap.

See [Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6) in Block Programming Topics for details.

Stack frames do not retain anything, and nothing retains stack frames. Stack frames can't "do" anything (they're just offsets into the stack). And there's nothing to retain (they're just offsets into the stack). Stack frames cannot survive the exiting of their scope.

<strike>Queues effectively retain blocks that are added to them (and blocks effectively retain their queue until they are executed). By "effectively" I just mean that "there is a strong reference that will prevent it from being destroyed." Whether this is actually implemented with a call to `objc_retain` is an implementation detail.</strike>

EDIT: That last paragraph may confuse more than it illuminates. Calls to `dispatch_async` actually "copy" the block, rather than retain it. But the term "copy" here is not quite the same as what it means for other objects. It really is referring to moving a block from the stack to the heap, and your interviewers are probably exploring the MRC issue that you do not retain blocks that you want to hold onto, you copy them. But in ARC this has moved under the covers, and it's better to think about it in terms of strong references, which is the point I was hoping to make. When you call [dispatch_async](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453057-dispatch_async?language=objc#), it automatically handles copying the block for you, and releasing the block when it is complete (this is documented behavior; see link; this is true for both MRC and ARC). So you don't have to maintain a separate reference to the block to keep it around while it is on the queue (that would be very inconvenient).

The fact that blocks also maintain a reference to the queue until they're executed is documented in [dispatch_queue_create](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453030-dispatch_queue_create?language=objc#).

Comment: Thanks , there's so much confused to talk about blocks on the Internet such as in blogs that copy other confused bloggers. I now see that the thing that is often referred to as the stack frame is actually a struct, which includes a function pointer.

Comment: Believe it or not a "top five tech company" interviewer insisted that queues do not retain blocks. I suppose this might makes sense for global blocks which can't be retained or destroyed anyway because they are constant.

Comment: I hope I haven't misled here; the interviewer may have been referring to a different aspect of blocks. (But block and queues absolutely do form a retain loop until the block is executed.) Edited to hopefully be more clear. (And agreed, the thing you're probably thinking about is a struct that contains information about the block, not a stack frame. See https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/closure/Block_private.h for some details, particularly `Block_layout`)

Comment: "Stack variables referenced by a block are referenced on the stack until the block is moved to the heap. At that time, any automatic variables are copied along with the block, and any `__block` variables are copied to the heap." Non-`__block` captured variables are captured by value into the block *at the time the block is created*, not when the block is moved to the heap. Perhaps you mean that when the stack block is moved to the heap, since the captured copy of the variables are in the stack block, they are moved to the heap block too.

Comment: @newacct Yes, that's a better way to say it. They are definitely captured at creation, but may be copied later. (As I recall, the optimizer will avoid the copy entirely on the stack if it can determine that the value does not change.)